# Excel to PSPP without with hassle with variable names

Tags: excel

I have some data in excel file. Now I need to find their significance value which is not possible with excel. It is only possible with PSPP. But when I import my excel file (after converting to csv file) to pspp it is making hell lot of problems specially with variable names. 
Could anyone please tell me some easy solutions?

Comment: What does you excel file look like? What are these _problems_ you met? I would suggest having a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Excel to PSPP: Make sure your excel file is prepared:

- Red boxes in the `import-process` of the cvs-file indicate problems in the rows, like words added in what otherwise looks like a variable with numeric values.
- The variable names must not be too long so fix that first, it works like a very old version of SPSS in this respect.
- Then look carefully at the steps when importing.

  - Choose the second row to be the first (as the first row is variable names, and not a case).
  - Then click the box for choosing the top row as variable names.

It is less smooth than SPSS in the initial procedure, but so fantastic with a free alternative to the SPSS.

When the dataset is ready, I found it worked well to do the same analyzes as in SPSS.

I suppose your problem is solved a long time ago, but maybe someone else may benefit from this.
A site for sharing information about the PSPP would be great...

Answer (score -1):

One should first convert excel file into CSV (maybe through Apple Mac software Number) and then import the converted into PSPP software...easy